# How to add snp/indels from a CSV file to a FASTA file using Biopython?

Tags: python, csv, biopython, fasta, mutation

I want to modify the sequences of a FASTA file. My FASTA contains the human genome (the sequence of each chromosome) with ids being `>1`, `>2`,... `>22`, `>X`, `>Y`, `>MT` and `>GL000207.1`.

The modifications (mutations) that I would like to introduce in each of the chromosome sequence are located in a CSV file. An example is shown here:

```
chrom;position;ref;var;Gene;VAR
1;21424;C;T;WASH7P;snp.LOH
1;33252099;CACATGCATGACTATTCCTAGCC;-;YARS;indel_somatic
5;107061668;-;GT;EFNA5(dist=55072),FBXL17(dist=133066);indel_somatic
22;22677038;G;C;BMS1P20;snp_somatic
MT;16093;T;C;NONE(dist=NONE),NONE(dist=NONE);snp.LOH
X;22012649;-;T;SMS;indel_somatic
```

in which each line describes the chromosome number, the position on the chromosome at which the snp/indel is found. The next two columns indicate the reference nucleotide and the mutation that has to be inserted in the FASTA file. This modification can be a substitution, a deletion (of more than one nt) or an insertion (of more than one nucleotide). The last two columns are not important. The output should be the new FASTA with the mutations.

I have created the following script. I know I'm far from what I wanted to do... I will try to improve but it the meantime if someone can give some advice, it would be more than welcome.

```
from bisect import bisect_right
from collections import defaultdict
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import MutableSeq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
import csv

def line_to_snp(line):
    row = line.split(";")
    return row[0], int(row[1]), row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]


with open('Modified_build.fasta', 'w') as f1:
   reference = SeqIO.read("human_g1k_v37.fasta", "fasta")
   datafile = open('snp_all.csv', 'r')
   snp = line_to_snp(line)
   for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(reference):
    mutable_seq = MutableSeq (reference, IUPACUnambigousDNA())
    if snp[0] == seq_record.id:
           mutable_seq[snp[1]] = snp[3]
           f1.write(seq_id)
           f1.write(seq_record)
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts at solving this problem? Do you have any code to show? The [Biopython tutorial](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html) should be a good starting point for familiarizing yourself with reading/writing FASTA records.

Comment: Yes I have added what I've done so far...

Comment: Okay, great! Now, what specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know how to specifically change a nucleotide of the fasta file for one specifically identified in the csv file. If we look at the example above, I would like change to change the nucleotide 21424 for a T in the chromosome 1 of the fasta file

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is a good start, but your code doesn't do anything with the CSV file opened (`datafile` isn't touched, and `line` is undefined).

I would build an accession-keyed dictionary of data from your SNP file. You can use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to read the `;`-delimited file. When iterating over the `SeqRecord` objects, you can get mutation data from this dictionary.

Miscellaneous errors:

- `MutableSeq` can't modify a record, only a string or a `Seq`.
- Python strings (and thus `Seq` objects) use zero-based indexing, wheras sequence indices are one-based.
- undefined name `IUPACUnambiguousDNA` (this is part of `IUPAC`)

---

My suggestion is to use an approach like the one below:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio.Seq import MutableSeq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

import csv


# Build a dictionary of position & mutation by accession
snp_dict = {}
with open('snp_all.csv') as snp_all:
    csv_data = csv.reader(snp_all, delimiter=';')
    header = next(csv_data)
    for chrom, position, ref, var, _, _ in csv_data:
        snp_dict[chrom] = (int(position), ref, var)

# Iterate over (missing) FASTA file, create mutations
mutated_records = []
reference = SeqIO.read("human_g1k_v37.fasta", "fasta")
for record in SeqIO.parse("this_file_missing.fasta", "fasta"):
    mutable_seq = MutableSeq(reference.seq, IUPAC.IUPACUnambigousDNA())
    if record.id in snp_dict:  # Are all sequences mutated in snp_all?
        position, ref, var = snp_dict[record.id]
        mutable_seq[position - 1] = var
        record.seq = mutable_seq.toseq()  # Re-use the record- preserves id, etc.
        mutated_records.append(record)

with open('Modified_build.fasta', 'w') as f1:
    SeqIO.write(mutated_records, f1, "fasta")
```